# Estimate for the binomial coefficients and bounds from below for the Beta function

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

Let $n\ge p\in \mathbb N$ and let $\binom{n}{p}$ be the binomial coefficient. I believe that
$$
\binom{n}{p}\le 2^n\sqrt\frac{2}{π n}.
$$
Question: is that true? Of course I would like it as a non-asymptotic result, valid for all integers $n,p$. A related estimate would be a bound from below for the Beta function with
$$
B(x,y)\ge \frac{\sqrt{(y-1)(x-1)}}{2^{x+y-1}}\sqrt\frac{π(x+y-1)}{2},\quad x,y\ge 1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

There is an elegant way to get the bounds for the binomial coefficients, using that the middle binomial coefficient is the largest.

First consider the even case, and put 
$$ 
a_n = \binom{2n}{n} \frac{\sqrt{2n}}{4^n}. 
$$ 
By Stirling's formula it is clear that $a_n \to \sqrt{2/\pi}$ as $n\to \infty$ and we want the inequality $a_n < \sqrt{2/\pi}$ for all $n$.  This holds because the sequence $a_n$ is monotone increasing, which we may see by computing 
$$ 
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{(2n+1)}{2(n+1)} = \Big( 1+ \frac{1}{4n^2+4n} \Big)^{\frac 12} > 1.
$$

Now consider the odd case, and put 
$$ 
b_n = \binom{2n+1}{n} \frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}}.
$$ 
Once again it is enough to show that $b_n$ is monotone increasing, and again we compute readily that 
$$ 
\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}} = \frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n-1}} \frac{(2n+1)}{2(n+1)} = \Big( \frac{(2n+1)^3}{4(2n-1)(n+1)^2} \Big)^{\frac 12} > 1. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

What do you get if you simply use a fairly precise version of Stirling's formula for the three factorials in $\binom{n}{p}$? For example, try using
$$
\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot n^{n+1/2}\cdot e^{-n+1/(12n+1)}
< n! <
\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot n^{n+1/2}\cdot e^{-n+1/12n}.
$$
And if that's not good enough, there are better estimates available. If I have a chance later, I'll try to work out the details, unless you do it first.

Comment: For p small (say 3p less than n), the pth coefficient is not much smaller than the sum, for which many estimates can be found on this forum for sum of binomial coefficients.  Gerhard "And Also Many References Therein" Paseman, 2018.07.05.

Answer (score 0):

The estimate you state holds and is standard. Various Internet references on this exist, do a search for binomial coefficients.

For small $p$, one can approximate the coefficient with $(en/p)^p$ and $(e(n-p)/p)^p$, and with care one can prove for which $n$ and $p$ these strictly bound the coefficient. For $ \mid n-2p \mid \leq \sqrt{4\pi n}$, your posted bound is easiest and suffices for most applications.  If you need really fine control, it may be best to estimate a product of a few terms of $(n-k)/k$ by an appropriate power of 2 and use that.

For $p$ not small and not close to $n/2$, the bound you choose may depend on the application. Most of the "mass" of the binomial distribution is centered around $n/2$, and likely good estimates for the tails are also found with an Internet search.

Gerhard "Found Lots On The Internet" Paseman, 2018.07.05.

Comment: If you're going to say "Let me google that for you", then you should actually report on the Google search!

Comment: I thought I was saying indirectly "it can be searched and I am suggesting a certain someone else do it".  Gerhard "Is Avoiding Saying Company Names" Paseman, 2018.07.05.

Comment: I don't see the point.  If you already searched and found the references where this is done, why not state that?

Comment: Because I haven't searched. I have contributed answers to a related question, indirectly referenced the questions that have contributed answers and references, and have a hazy recollection of web pages that have related information.  I would like to promote the idea to the poster that if the poster does the search, they will be rewarded. I would not like to promote the idea that I will do it for them.  Gerhard "Makes Perfect Sense To Me" Paseman, 2018.07.05.